# Regex for "-day every" OR "every -day time" convert - with NOT if we give "every-day" it should not convert in perl

Tags: regex, perl

How to make regex for `-day every` OR `every -day time`  convert `-` with `NOT` if we give `every-day` it should not convert  in Perl.

For example: if we give `-day every` it should convert it to `NOT day every` .

But we give `every-day` it should not convert it.

I have used the regex as mentioned `s/(?<!\w)-/NOT /g;` and it works fine but i have an another case where we don't need to convert dash (-) if (-) belongs under double quotes "".

Like an example: keyword = "every - day" -time light.

It should convert "every - day" NOT time light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to replace any dash not following a word character: `s/(?<!\w)-/NOT /g;`

Now updated the regex to to the same, except not within double quotes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s{(".*?")|(?<!\w)-}{$1 // 'NOT '}esg;
    print;
}

__DATA__
-day every
every -day time
every-day
"every - day" -time light.
```

Outputs:

```
NOT day every
every NOT day time
every-day
"every - day" NOT time light.
```

Comment: I have used the regex as mentioned s/(?<!\w)-/NOT /g; and it works fine but i have an another case where we don't need to convert dash (-) if (-) belongs under double quotes "".

Like an example: keyword = "every - day" -time light.

It should convert "every - day" NOT time light.

Comment: Updated for your roving specification.  If this is the answer you're looking for, give it the check mark to close out the question.